# How to find proper noun using spacy nlp

Tags: python, spacy

Im using spacy to build a keyword extractor. The key word im looking for is `OpTic Gaming` in the following text.

> "The company was also one of OpTic Gaming's main sponsors during the
> legendary organization's run to their first Call of Duty Championship
> back in 2017"

How can i parse `OpTic Gaming` from this text. If use noun_chunks i get `OpTic Gaming's main sponsors sponsors` and if i get tokens i get ["OpTic", "Gaming", "'s"].

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp("The company was also one of OpTic Gaming's main sponsors during the legendary organization's run to their first Call of Duty Championship back in 2017")

for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text, chunk.root.text, chunk.root.dep_,
            chunk.root.head.text)
```

> The company company nsubj was
>
> OpTic Gaming's main sponsors sponsors pobj of
>
> their first Call Call pobj to
>
> Duty Championship Championship pobj of

Answer (score 6):

Spacy extracts Part-of-speech for you (proper noun, determinant, verb, etc.). You can access them at a token level with  `token.pos_`

In your case:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("The company was also one of OpTic Gaming's main sponsors during the legendary organization's run to their first Call of Duty Championship back in 2017")

for tok in doc:
    print(tok, tok.pos_)
```

> ...
>
> one NUM
>
> of ADP
>
> OpTic **PROPN**
>
> Gaming **PROPN**
>
> ...

You can then filter on proper noun, group consecutive proper nouns, and slice the doc to get nominal groups:

```
def extract_proper_nouns(doc):
    pos = [tok.i for tok in doc if tok.pos_ == "PROPN"]
    consecutives = []
    current = []
    for elt in pos:
        if len(current) == 0:
            current.append(elt)
        else:
            if current[-1] == elt - 1:
                current.append(elt)
            else:
                consecutives.append(current)
                current = [elt]
    if len(current) != 0:
        consecutives.append(current)
    return [doc[consecutive[0]:consecutive[-1]+1] for consecutive in consecutives]
```

> extract_proper_nouns(doc)
>
> [OpTic Gaming, Duty Championship]

More details here: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Answer (score 0):

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "New Delhi is a Capital of India"

doc = nlp(text)

full_entities = {}
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ in ["PERSON", "ORG", "GPE"] and " " in ent.text:
        if ent.label_ not in full_entities:
            full_entities[ent.label_] = []
        full_entities[ent.label_].append(ent.text)

if not full_entities:
    proper_nouns = [token.text for token in doc if token.pos_ == "PROPN"]
    for i, token in enumerate(proper_nouns[:-1]):
        if proper_nouns[i+1].istitle() and not token.endswith("."):
            if "PERSON" not in full_entities:
                full_entities["PERSON"] = []
            full_entities["PERSON"].append(token + " " + proper_nouns[i+1])

print(full_entities)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76180776/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).